# Elasticsearch - [fuzzy] query does not support [fuzziness]

Tags: elasticsearch

I am receiving an error when querying elasticsearch - [fuzzy] query does not support [fuzziness]

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/searches_development_20140329164207570/search_term/_search/?pretty=true" -d '{
"query": {
  "fuzzy": {
    "displayname": {
      "value": "altanta",
      "fuzziness": 2
    }
  }
}
}'
```

Examining the query DSL this is the correct way to go about performing a fuzzy query http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html

It is not immediately clear to me what I am doing wrong - if i remove the 'fuzziness' option, the query validates but it is supported according to the documentation. Why is exception being thrown?

Here is some sample data I hope to match on https://gist.github.com/lfender6445/b4fba20c2736a017584e

Here is the complete error message:

```
{
  "error" : "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[1daKAcneQXeFsEfxPwKEmg][searches_development_20140329164207570][4]: SearchParseException[[searches_development_20140329164207570][4]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n\"query\": {\n  \"fuzzy\": {\n    \"displayname\": {\n      \"value\": \"altanta\",\n      \"fuzziness\": 2\n    }\n  }\n}\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[searches_development_20140329164207570] [fuzzy] query does not support [fuzziness]]; }{[1daKAcneQXeFsEfxPwKEmg][searches_development_20140329164207570][2]: SearchParseException[[searches_development_20140329164207570][2]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n\"query\": {\n  \"fuzzy\": {\n    \"displayname\": {\n      \"value\": \"altanta\",\n      \"fuzziness\": 2\n    }\n  }\n}\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[searches_development_20140329164207570] [fuzzy] query does not support [fuzziness]]; }{[1daKAcneQXeFsEfxPwKEmg][searches_development_20140329164207570][3]: SearchParseException[[searches_development_20140329164207570][3]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n\"query\": {\n  \"fuzzy\": {\n    \"displayname\": {\n      \"value\": \"altanta\",\n      \"fuzziness\": 2\n    }\n  }\n}\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[searches_development_20140329164207570] [fuzzy] query does not support [fuzziness]]; }{[1daKAcneQXeFsEfxPwKEmg][searches_development_20140329164207570][0]: SearchParseException[[searches_development_20140329164207570][0]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n\"query\": {\n  \"fuzzy\": {\n    \"displayname\": {\n      \"value\": \"altanta\",\n      \"fuzziness\": 2\n    }\n  }\n}\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[searches_development_20140329164207570] [fuzzy] query does not support [fuzziness]]; }{[1daKAcneQXeFsEfxPwKEmg][searches_development_20140329164207570][1]: SearchParseException[[searches_development_20140329164207570][1]: from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{\n\"query\": {\n  \"fuzzy\": {\n    \"displayname\": {\n      \"value\": \"altanta\",\n      \"fuzziness\": 2\n    }\n  }\n}\n}]]]; nested: QueryParsingException[[searches_development_20140329164207570] [fuzzy] query does not support [fuzziness]]; }]",
  "status" : 400
}  


elasticsearch -v
Version: 0.90.11, Build: 11da1ba/2014-02-03T15:27:39Z, JVM: 1.6.0_65
```

Comment: please provide some sample data that you expect to match

Comment: https://gist.github.com/lfender6445/b4fba20c2736a017584e

Comment: I don't get any errors. Can you post the complete error message, too, please?

Comment: Sorry, but works for me. Have a look at the [example](https://gist.github.com/ThorstenS/11193188) I tested it with. Tested on ES 1.1.1

Comment: thanks for providing build information. I upgraded and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by upgrading to `ES 1.1.1`

Comment: For the reference, the property was called [`min_similarity` in ES 0.90.x](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/0.90/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html)